# Eclipse can't resolve SFML 2.0 object members

Tags: c++, eclipse, sfml, eclipse-juno

My problem does not look like a rare case (even though I could find nothing on the issue), nor is it the most important of issues but I figured it would be worth asking.

I use SFML 2.0 release candidate ([Download here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php)) for Linux 32 bits. 
When trying an example it built perfectly and ran as it was supposed. However, in Eclipse every line where a method of let's say, an sf::Window, was called it would be marked as "Method can't be resolved" and I'd get the red squibbly line. Note this doesn't affect the actual building.

This is not the gravest of inconveniences but it does clutter up my screen and make it harder to detect actual errors in my code.

Some extra info concerning my work space: The version of my Eclipse should be Juno. For this code I use a standard Makefile and link again sfml-graphics, sfml-window and sfml-system; the ones that matter. For compiling I use g++.

Any help as to get this nuisance fixed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Juno on Ubuntu 12.04 and this are the steps I had to take to make SFML play nice with Juno:

Right click on your project and navigate to `Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> All Options`. This settings looks like

[image: Compileflags]

`Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries` looks like this:

[image: Libraries]

The other settings were CDT defaults for me.